# How to set the background of a View on Motorola Cliq

Tags: android, background, motorola

I have developed a hidden object game for Android. I tested it on a variety of phones before launching it, and it works exactly intended on all of them.

I have come across a weird problem that seems to only pertain to the Motorola Cliq. It force closes the app every time it tries to start.

After using the desperate "comment everything out" method of tracking down the bug, I found that the line "android:background="scrollb" in the RelativeLayout is the problem. How do I get around this? Why does it only happen with the Cliq?

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:background="scrollb" android:id="@+id/TableLayout01" android:paddingLeft="5mm" android:paddingRight="5mm" android:gravity = "center_horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"   android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView06" android:text="" android:textSize = "10mm" android:gravity = "center_horizontal"  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
<TextView android:clickable="true" android:layout_below="@id/TextView06" android:textColor="#8b4513" android:textStyle="italic" android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Play as Guest" android:textSize = "3mm" android:gravity = "center_horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"></TextView>
<TextView android:clickable="true" android:layout_below="@id/TextView01" android:textColor="#8b4513" android:textStyle="italic" android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" android:textSize = "3mm" android:gravity = "center_horizontal"  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:visibility="gone"></TextView>
<TextView android:clickable="true" android:layout_below="@id/TextView02" android:textColor="#8b4513" android:textStyle="italic" android:id="@+id/TextView03" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" android:textSize = "3mm" android:gravity = "center_horizontal"  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:visibility="gone"></TextView>
<TextView android:clickable="true" android:layout_below="@id/TextView03" android:textColor="#8b4513" android:textStyle="italic" android:id="@+id/TextView04" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" android:textSize = "3mm" android:gravity = "center_horizontal"  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:visibility="gone"></TextView>
<TextView android:clickable="true" android:layout_below="@id/TextView04" android:textColor="#8b4513" android:textStyle="italic" android:id="@+id/TextView05" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" android:textSize = "3mm" android:gravity = "center_horizontal"  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:visibility="gone"></TextView>

<EditText  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:gravity = "center_horizontal" android:layout_below="@id/TextView05" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:text="" android:id="@+id/EditText01"></EditText>

<Button android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_below="@id/EditText01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Create Player" android:id="@+id/Button01" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
<TextView  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:gravity = "center_horizontal" android:layout_below="@id/Button01" android:textColor="#8b4513" android:textStyle="italic" android:id="@+id/TextView07" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Welcome to Hidden Treasures,\n your journey awaits"></TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Heres the stack trace: *Note, I changed the Relative layout to a Linear one

```
04-08 13:39:50.646: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.htf/com.htf.main}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2313)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:115)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1721)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3977)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class java.lang.reflect.Constructor
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:512)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:562)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:313)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1683)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at com.htf.main.onCreate(main.java:33)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2260)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     ... 11 more
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:92)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:499)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     ... 21 more
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/title_bar_shadow.9.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f020068
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1643)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:548)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1739)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1688)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:271)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     ... 25 more
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable/title_bar_shadow.9.png
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:417)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1636)
04-08 13:39:50.696: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(781):     ... 29 more
```

Comment: Your layout file doesn't tell us anything. As adamp suggested, if you can post a stack trace of the exception (if it's force closing there will be an exception) then it would help.

Comment: I added the stack trace. I also noticed that the emulutor is showing a default icon instead of the icon i set for my game. That would hint that something is very wrong with the resources, but this only happens with the motorola cliq? Doesn't make sense to me. Have to love fragmentation...

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Android uses the three  folders for hdpi, mdpi, ldpi. Motorola cliq tries to access the resources by looking in drawable.  Just drawable, no hdpi, mdpi, ldpi. Which of course doesnt exist.